# How do I add gray grid lines to a three-dimensional plot using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, 3d, coordinates

I am trying to use `pgfplots` to draw a three-dimensional space. Using the following code I'm able to get the axes to show, and I know how to add coordinates and nodes and some other objects:

```
\documentclass [border = .2cm] {standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} [
    axis lines*=middle,
    grid style={line width=3pt},%, draw=gray!40},
    major grid style={line width=4pt},%,draw=gray!90},
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    zmin=-10,zmax=10,
    xtick={0},
    ytick={0},
    ztick={0},
    ]
    
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That code produces this:

[image]

What I would like, though, is to have the other grid lines off the major axes appear in gray. I don't know how to say this any more clearly--basically what I want is something like this:

[image]

Ignore the tick marks and the labels for the axes--all I care about is reproducing the gray coordinate lines on the *xy* plane. I've been through the documentation for `pgfplots` and cannot figure out what I'm missing. If it's possible, I'd also be interested in drawing the grids for the *z* plane too.

Answer (score 1):

With that gaph I think the only solution is to plot a surface or a rectangular path to simulate the grid, you can play easily with colors, opacity et c. This is an example of both, you can also display all the planes you want.(Adjusted using @hpekristiansen answer)

```
\documentclass [border = .2cm] {standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  view={35}{15},
  axis lines=center,
  xtick={false},ytick={false},ztick={false},
  width=15cm,height=15cm,
  xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10,zmin=-10,zmax=10,
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$},
  axis on top,
 ]
\addplot3 [patch, patch refines=4, patch type=rectangle, white, faceted color=red!50 ]  coordinates {(-8,0,8) (8,0,8) (8,0,-8) (-8,0,-8)};
\addplot3[mesh, gray!50, domain=-8:8, samples=17, domain y=-8:8, samples y=17] {0}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines*=middle,
xmin=-10, xmax=10,
ymin=-10, ymax=10,
zmin=-10, zmax=10,
ticks=none,
axis on top,
]
\addplot3[mesh, gray!40, domain=-8:8, samples=11, domain y=-8:8, samples y=11, forget plot] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D axis with grid in x y plane]